# Eclipse - How come Generate Getters and Setters does not consider "By Reference"

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

if java is always pass variables by reference, why does eclipse generate the bean with out any consideration.

instead of:
`return myStr;`

needs to be
`return new String(myStr);`

no?

**Edit**
Ok, my example was bad.
lets leave eclipse, When I want to return a Custom object. Do i need to create a "copy constructor" and return it, like that:

```
return new MyCustomObject(myCustomObject);


class MyCustomObject{

  private String str; 
  public MyCustomObject(String str){
    this.str = str;
  }

  public MyCustomObject(MyCustomObject obj){
    this.str =  obj.str;    
  }
}
```

Must I write that?

Comment: `String` is immutable; there's no point returning a new one.

Comment: Java is always pass by value.  Object references are also pass by value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

In Java, every object variable is a reference. Objects cannot be passed by value, only primitives can (and always are). Well, that's slightly misleading. The *reference* is passed by value, but you can think of everything being a reference, just not in a C++ sense.

Perhaps it's easiest to use an example.

```
SomeObject foo;

public void doSomething(SomeObject bar) {
    bar.whatever();
    bar = new SomeObject();
    bar.someOtherMethod();
}

public void doStuff() {
    foo = new SomeObject();
    doSomething(foo);
}
```

So, `foo` is a reference to an instance of `SomeObject`. When `doSomething` is called, the value of that reference is copied to `bar`, so now `foo` and `bar` are references to the same `SomeObject`.

The line `bar.whatever()` calls `whatever` on the same object that `foo` refers to.

`bar = new SomeObject()` means that `foo` and `bar` now refer to *different* `SomeObject` instances, so `someOtherMethod` is **not** called on the object that `foo` refers to.

This is completely different to C++, where

```
void doSomething(SomeObject& bar) {
    bar = whatever;
}
```

has a totally different meaning. You really should not ever think of Java in C++ terms.

Regarding your example, `String`s are immutable in Java so it wouldn't matter even if objects *could* be passed by value.

Regarding your second example, if you want to return an object that the caller cannot use to pollute your internal state then, yes, you need to have a copy constructor (or something equivalent).

For example:

```
class ClassWithInternalList {
    private List<String> reallyImportantData;

    public List<String> getImmutableViewOfData() {
        // Take advantage of the java.util.Collections tool for making a List immutable.
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(reallyImportantData);
    }

    public List<String> getSafeCopyOfData() {
        // Return a copy that the caller can modify without changing reallyImportantData.
        return new ArrayList<String>(reallyImportantData);
    }

    public List<String> justGetTheData() {
        // Return a reference to reallyImportantData that the caller can modify at will.
        return reallyImportantData;
    }
}
```

You can choose the appropriate type of return value (normal reference, immutable view or copy) depending on the situation. Any or all of the three options could be appropriate depending on exactly what you are doing.

`java.util.Collections` makes it easy to get an immutable view of a `Collection`, but for custom classes you'll need to do your own immutable-ness.

Remember that you only need to do this if there is an issue with mutability. Your `MyCustomObject` example is still immutable (since the caller cannot change any state in the returned `MyCustomObject` instance), so the question is still kinda moot.

Answer (score 0):

If the variable is primitive or immutable,you modify what returned won't influence the original property.

Other condition, the variable is a custom type,maybe your class defines a constructor with itself like String,maybe not . So eclipse does not know how to generate it's copy.

As all knows,java pass reference,so java programmers are used to return the reference and allow other modify.Eclipse implement it as default.

If you don't like it ,you can return a copy or implements Immutable.

Comment: An object is considered immutable if its state cannot change after it is constructed. Maximum reliance on immutable objects is widely accepted as a sound strategy for creating simple, reliable code.
Immutable objects are particularly useful in concurrent applications. Since they cannot change state, they cannot be corrupted by thread interference or observed in an inconsistent state.

Comment: So, if you can have a look at my edit, does the copy constructor is not necessarily?

Comment: Sorry,I have just noticed that you have edit it.I think in general we don't need to make all class implement Immutable,because it deviate from the convention,and allocate too many objects.Except you have strong reason to protect it from modify.

Answer (score -1):

You usually do not want to create a new object when using getter. What you usually want is to get the reference to object's attribute to work with it easier, for encapsulation and to have the right value even when something else changes the value of the attribute before you use it.

Creating a new instance of an object by method which is called often, is not expected to do it and even does not declare doing such thing is freaking **anti-pattern**.

Comment: It's not at all an anti-pattern, and is often needed precisely to keep encapsulation and make sure an object is immutable. For example, String.getChars(...) always returns a new char array, and that's a good thing. Making a defensive copy of a Date (which is mutable) is very often a good idea. Wrapping a list into an unmodifiable list is often a very good idea.

Comment: Apparently you did no read my answer carefully. For example String.getChars() does not create the destination array, it's one of of the parameters and documentation clearly states something is copied. Using immutable types or wrappers is a completely different story.

Comment: Well, copy constructors are used mainly to maintain immutability, and the OP asks if he should use them, so I wouldn't say that it's a completely different story. BTW all the answers except yours talk about immutability.

Comment: Well, I admit the only difference is in that that there is a new class created for that. I wonder if I overlooked something in question or it was edited  - the title asks about getters and the code below does not look like copy constructor at all.